# How can i read cookies in rails that have been set by jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I am setting a cookie in jquery like this(works fine and the cookie is generated):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var consp = $("input[home]").attr("home");
    $("input[name='commit']").click(function() {
        $.cookie('home', consp);
    });
});
```

In my controller i am trying to get hold of that cookies value. So i am using standard READing of cookies like this

```
def some_method
    @value = cookies[:home]
end
```

But when i output the value of @value, nothing is returned. This only happens if i set the cookie using jquery, however does not happen if i set the cookie directly through rails(no jquery). Any thoughts as to why this occurs? thanks

Comment: Here's the same method @Hishalv suggested, using the [Mozilla's Cookie Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099420/set-a-cookie-from-view-then-read-it-from-controller-in-rails/40298349#answer-40298349).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, figured this one out:

I was creating this cookie when i was submitting a form and due to the mvc architecture, rails was submitting to a create action and the redirecting back to orginal page upon successfull redirect. So i needed this cookie to be valid across all pages so [jquery.cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

The solution was to pass the path parameter into the mix like this

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```

This then allows the cookie to be read from all page routes.