# Set a cookie from view, then read it from Controller in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cookies

I would like to set cookie value from within Rails view using Javascript, then use Controller to read this cookie. Is this possible with Rails, and how should I go about it?

My situation: I have an input field (say, address) that user needs to fill out when s/he first comes to my site. The user then logs in using Omniauth. I would like to persist address until after he logs in.

Update: 
I was able to add to document.cookies on client. However, cookies["something"] returns nil from Rails end. Below is the cookie hash:

`#<ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieJar:0x007 @secret="f4d518c0b2", @set_cookies={}, @delete_cookies={}, @host="localhost", @secure=false, @closed=false, @cookies={"_myapp_session"=>"BAh7Ck==--776b2fcfcd63d3c84d2b1de5327e277499add6d4", "fbsr_1505068851081"=>"mqZeyvoRC"}, @signed=#<ActionDispatch::Cookies::SignedCookieJar:0x007 @parent_jar=#<ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieJar:0x007fdf...>, @verifier=#<ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier:0x007fdfa34548d8 @secret="f4d518c0b2e9d8", @digest="SHA1", @serializer=Marshal>>>`

Answer (score 12):

To set a cookie in javascript you can do:

`document.cookie="something= test";`

So you can add an event (click, submit, ..) to get the value from the input and create a cookie the way i mentioned above.

In rails you can read the value like this:

`cookies["something"]`

*You can also specify when the cookie will expire in javascript if you need to.*

Comment: thanks for the answer. I got the first part works. But I can't get cookies["something"] as you said in the second part. It seems that the cookies are signed, so I can't alter it. Do you know of a way to get around this? Thanks again.

Comment: @AdamNYC, could you try `cookies.signed["something"]`?

Comment: I tried cookies.signed["something"] but it is nil. I updated the cookie hash in my question.

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer**

1. Install the [MDN JavaScript Cookie Framework](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie/Simple_document.cookie_framework)
2. On your js file:

   ```
   docCookies.setItem('my_cookie', 'my_cookie_value', '', '/');
   ```
3. On your rails controller:

   ```
   cookies[:my_cookie]
   ```

**Not so short answer**

Rails [ActionDispatch::Cookies](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html) defaults the cookie path to the **root of the application**, while [plain JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#Write_a_new_cookie) defaults it to the **current path**.

This means that if you don't declare the path, you'll end up with two different cookies bearing the same name and a headache.

In order to troubleshoot this you can use the 'Application/Cookies' on the Chrome DevTools window so you can see all the details for each cookie and reload their values as you modify them via the 'Console' panel.

Answer (score 0):

This may explain your problem.  Apparently you need to make sure the cookie's path lines up.

[How can i read cookies in rails that have been set by jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932865/how-can-i-read-cookies-in-rails-that-have-been-set-by-jquery)